# qgis2web can't create map w/ large dataset, and potentially utilizing GeoServer

Tags: qgis, geoserver, qgis2web

I have a very large dataset (about 120k records) and about a dozen layers, all focused on California for the moment. That is, all the shapes like zips, census tracts, counties etc. are selected using the query builder to narrow to just this state.

My issue is when I try to export a qgis2web map on my Win7, what ends up happening is my computer disk space gets maxed out to whatever I have available (currently 65GB) as there is a .tif file being created (ostensibly by the qgis2web plugin but, I'm not certain it's not a setting or another plugin conflict). Is that the norm and am I simply supposed to provide more disk space for such a gigantic image file?

I'm also using a hosted GeoServer to host my shapefiles and have my data in a postgres/postGIS-extended database. My belief is it's somewhat foolish to parse all that data in QGIS to create a map when in effect the data and shapes for the map I end up making (in OpenLayers or Leaflet) will be called from GeoServer.

Is there a way to minimize the load on QGIS w/ qgis2web so that it can do it's job more efficiently and I load the GeoJSON file with the 112k data records manually?

QGIS 2.16.1 | qgis2web v1.13.1 | GeoServer 2.9.0 | Postgres 9.5.4 | PostGIS 2.2.2r14797

Comment: Are any of the layers rasters? My understanding is that qgis2web outputs geojson's rather than rasters. I haven't had success getting the qgis2web plugin to work for raster layers. It seems that this is where "tiling" typically comes in. You could try running qgis2web with just a single layer, getting the basic framework/index.html for the webpage, and then manually adding the rest of the layers...

Comment: If all my shapes and data are hosted via my Postgre/PostGIS GeoServer, isn't there a way to call the data from there using server-side processing vs loading all the geojson data into the map sourcecode itself? 

I also wonder if there's a reason I'm not seeing why the qgis2web crashes or can't produce a big enough file. Isn't that a function of my computer's memory (processing time) and my level of patience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your Geoserver layers, make sure you don't check "Encode to JSON". That should leave the layers as remote WFS layers. However, they will still load fully - I need to find out whether I can implement viewport bbox loading.

TIFFs are created if you have raster layers - disable any you have, I guess, since you imply that you don't expect to have any raster output.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Great job on this tool. You gave me a clue, and is it fair to say, that I should be creating my layers as WMS vs. starting and calling everything from GeoServer through the GeoExplorer. Would that allow me to create the export with qgis2web without so much (I'm assuming) overhead?

Comment: Yes, that would do it, definitely in the case of WMS, and with the proviso I mentioned above (which is probably a blocker for you) that WFS layers are (I think) downloaded completely, rather than just features visible. Further testing needed to confirm that last point, as it might differ between qgis2web's Leaflet and OpenLayers 3 output.

Comment: In a word, yes. Come back with any other questions or issues, probably as a new question

Comment: @civarchive I'm completely new to leaflet as well and have the same question. I have a Postgres db with spatial data but noticed qgis2web converts them to geojson. Did you have any success in accessing them directly from the sevrer? 

Ideally I want to be able to add a point on postgres which will update my map on the website.

Comment: @ChrisJenner You cannot query a database directly from a webpage. You need some software in between. The most common way to achieve this is with an WFS such as Geoserver, QGIS Server, or MapServer. Without that, qgis2web can only convert your PostGres data to GeoJSON.

Comment: @TomChadwin thanks for the response! So if I understand correctly I'd have to use a combination of GeoServer with leaflet? I'm a GIS professional but anything web I'm learning on the fly.

For ease of use, would I better using Postgres to store my spatial data and then just updating the geojson text in leaflet for every change?

Comment: If the GeoJSON is too big, and performance in the browser suffers, you'll need eg Geoserver. If performance is OK with the GeoJSON, and your data doesn't change too often, then yes, re-exporting when the data changes is an option.